# What are the requirements to become a language proficiency examiner?

Tags: easa-regulations, icao

What are the requirements to become a language proficiency examiner? Does the person have to be a pilot? Does it have to be a flight instructor?

What kind of language proficiency rating do they have to hold to test level 4 / 5 / 6? I guess they have to have 5 to test 4 and 6 to test 5 and 6, is that true?

Comment: A what? Never heard of of it? Please show a regulations that requires one?

Comment: @jwzumwalt The FAA had not adopted the ICAO English language requirements, so I suspect that's why you haven't heard of it.

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on the country. Some have no requirements for the training, others like the UK require the training organization to be approved by the national civil aviation authority,

Comment: @JuanJimenez could you expand that with a bit more details into an answer? That's basically what I'm looking for, maybe some links about it as well or some hints where I find more details or so

Comment: I need to know which country you're referring to before I can provide an answer.